# Convert comma separated unique values in to multiple columns filled with binary values(0/1)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

How to convert comma separated values in to multiple columns using python DataFrame, as shown in the figure?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ! Please use text instead of images so it will easier for community to copy the values and support you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can split each string base `','` then use [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
s = df['col1'].str.split(',')
df_new = pd.get_dummies(s.apply(pd.Series).stack()).groupby(level=0).sum()
print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
   s1  s2  s3  s4  s5
0   1   1   1   0   0
1   1   1   0   0   0
2   0   1   0   0   0
3   1   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   1   0   0
5   0   0   1   1   0
6   1   0   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use directly [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) and [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to the original DataFrame if you want to keep the original column(s):

```
out = df.join(df['col1'].str.get_dummies(sep=','))
```

output:

```
       col1  s1  s2  s3  s4  s5
0  s1,s2,s3   1   1   1   0   0
1     s1,s2   1   1   0   0   0
2        s2   0   1   0   0   0
3        s1   1   0   0   0   0
4        s3   0   0   1   0   0
5     s3,s4   0   0   1   1   0
6     s1,s5   1   0   0   0   1
```